# node.js EJS - Data in partial which is used multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am searching for advice on my nodejs project.
I've made a partial for a sidebar which needs some user data to be displayed on it. This sidebar is used multiple times throughout many pages in my project. In order to send the user data to the partial I always need to include it in every function where I render a page that uses the sidebar.

I'm now searching for a better solution, which let's me include the data at one place and the partial can use this data on every page that uses the sidebar.

Is this approach even possible with the combination nodejs/express/ejs or am I searching for the impossible?

Sample code to illustrate my problem:

**partial (sidebar):**

```html
<ul id="sidebarnav">
    <% if(user) { %>
    <li class="user-pro">
        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="/user/profile?id=<%= user.uuid %>"><i class="ti-user"></i> My Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="/auth/logout"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <% } %>
    <% if(user && user.permission.includes("ADMINISTRATION")) { %>
    <li>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="/system/users" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="ti-user"></i>
            <span class="hide-menu">Users</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

**page which uses the sidebar partial:**

```js
router.get("/", authMiddleware.checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render("app/index", {
        user: req.session.user
    });
});
router.get("/system/users", authMiddleware.checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render("app/system/users", {
        user: req.session.user
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two improvements I can suggest:

- EJS has an [include](https://ejs.co/#docs) system, basically embedding templates into templates. This makes it that instead of copying the sidebar code over and over again, you can simply include it.
- Serverside, you can have a simple "utility" function to add "default" data to your renders:

```js
function getDefaultData(req) {
    return { user: req.session.user; };
}
router.get("/", authMiddleware.checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render("app/index", getDefaultData(req));
});
router.get("/system/users", authMiddleware.checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render("app/system/users", {
        ...getDefaultData(req), // Inject all the default data
        users: getAllUsers(), // Add data specific to this page
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Kelvin,
Thanks for your advice! 
I've forgotten to point out that I'm already using the include system - but thank you anyway ;)
I have thought about the "default data function" aswell, but was searching for a more elegant solution. If nothing else is possible I'll stick with your "default data function" since it's the best approach so far!

Comment: Then besides making the existing easier/cleaner, and without ditching EJS, the only alternative is "reversing the include", basically have a main template in which you embed page templates, e.g. `res.render("app/layout", { page: 'app/system/users', ...pageData });` where the layout template includes the targeted page.

Comment: Interesting approach on inversing the includes! Imagine I'd ditch EJS, which alternatives will be available that have a better support or approach to "solve" my problem?

Comment: It's been a long while since I used templates with Express. Back then, I used something very similar to EJS (Phantom? forgot the name but you'd have the exact same problem). The only other framework combo that I know of is basically replacing EJS with React: a PWA (single-page web app) that performs REST requests (or GraphQL if that's your thing) to fetch/modify data from/on the server. Nowadays PWAs are a bit of a standard, but it's of course way different from EJS. You go from server-side rendering to client-side rendering. Now you'd need to transfer data to be rendered instead of pure HTML.

Comment: Mhm, seems like I've came to a certain spot where template languages no longer fullfill my needs in bringing clean and easy code out to the world ;) I'll stick with the "defaultDataFunction" approach for this app and will invest time to learn React for future projects.

Thank you very much for this conversation!